# Canonical url tag added in application.html.erb file is not working on all the pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, canonical-link

For SEO reasons I added `canonical` tag to the `application.html.erb` in the rails layouts, thinking all the urls being generated will have their own respective canonical url. But I checked it after pushing it to production. It doesn't seem like the `canonical` tag is working properly.

Following is the `canonical` tag added in my **application.html.erb**

`<link rel="canonical" href="<%= url_for(:only_path => false) %>" />`

When I checked on a online canonical checker, only the home page/root_url has a proper canonical url:

Page Url: `https://example.com/`

Canonical url: `https://example.com/`

Now when it comes to other landing pages, it is not working properly:

Issues 1:

Page url: `https://example.com/search?category_id=metal-processing-and-machine-tool`

Canonical url: `https://example.com/search`.

Issue 2:

Page url: `https://example.com/equipment_details/transformer-1250-kva-11-440-volts`

Canonical Url: **NONE**

This might cause a issue in SEO ranking. Could somebody please tell me how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at canonical-rails gem. After adding this gem to your app run `rails g canonical_rails:install`

Add `<%= canonical_tag -%>` to application.html.erb

**

> Check the below links for your reference:

**

https://github.com/jumph4x/canonical-rails

http://blog.planetargon.com/entries/easily-add-canonical-urls-to-your-rails-app